# Roslyn fluent syntax to create expression tree for multiline lambda

Tags: c#, .net, metaprogramming, expression-trees, roslyn

I am writing a Roslyn-based custom tool that tries to eradicate [CS0834](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397745.aspx) by rewriting given multi-line lambdas into Expression trees at build time.

**Edit**: At this time, I am only targeting anonymous multiline lambdas.

For example:

```
    // Will produce CS0834 if Bar takes Expression<Action<...>>
    Foo.Bar((int x) => { ... });
```

to

```
    Foo.Bar(Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(
        Expression.Block(
            ...
            ),
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(int))));
```

So that will compile correctly. While I can figure out the Expression.(blah) syntax required to convert the given code, doing it using Roslyn is another matter altogether. Perhaps I just don't know the Roslyn Syntax.(blah) API well enough to translate this raw lambda

```
    (int index, float[] a, float[] b) =>
    {
        var sum = 0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            sum += a[i];

        b[index] = sum;
    });
```

Could someone help me write the Roslyn Syntax.(blah) syntax that will generate an expression tree that looks like the one below?

```
    Expression<Action<int, float[], float[]>> action = 
        Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Block(
                Expression.Assign(sumParameter, Expression.Constant(0)),
                Expression.Loop(...) // The for loop here
                )
            );
```

Once I have a starting point - I ought to be able to figure out or at least get started translating simple cases in this project.

Many thanks, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have [a tool called Quoter that will generate Syntax.* API calls for any C# program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/07/22/roslyn-code-quoter-tool-generating-syntax-tree-api-calls-for-any-c-program.aspx).

You can [view it live at roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net).

If you figure out the logic to generate the Expression.* calls, you can easily generate code that generates it.

Update: the tool is now open-source! https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/RoslynQuoter

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yes - I know how to generate the corresponding Expression tree given a Roslyn syntax tree. I use a special visitor that walks the syntax tree but returns Expressions instead of SyntaxNodes. One related question, can I use Quoter in my open source application, Brahma (http://brahma.ananthonline.net) with full attribution? Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely. Quoter is under Apache 2.0 license, so you should be able to use it.

Comment: @ananthonline: did you ever get around of exploiting this information? Eg, is there a project which uses quoter to generate Expression.* calls?

Comment: TL;DR: No. The long version: I did write some of this code - but never to to extent of publishing a new version of Brahma that uses it. The code generation mechanism was VS-only which made it cumbersome and it wasn't useful for much else. I decided to hold off on Brahma till C# can generate expression trees for lambdas with bodies.